# Should I replace these resistors on my vintage radio?

Tags: resistors, radio, vintage

The one in the image isn't the 250k one exactly, but it's one I had a picture of. The 250k just has a different colour but is the same kind of resistor.

**EDIT, the big red one is a capacitor, the resistors are above and to the right of it**

[image]

I have a sheet telling me to use 250k resistors however they are measuring out to be 338k instead. I've done this with a couple other resistors and found them to all be slightly over what the data sheet calls for.

Is there a reason for this? Should I replace them or are they fine as they are? Also why are they so big? First time working with vintage components. Looking for any knowledge you guys have on this!

Comment: People are going to ask what kind of device this is so they have context for the purpose of the resistors.

Comment: The white ring at one end makes me think the part is polarized, so more likely a capacitor than a resistor.  When you measured the resistance, did you do it with the part in-circuit, or did you disconnect one end, so the surrounding circuit wouldn't affect the resistance reading?  Can you post the text printed on the part, or a more readable photo?

Comment: @PeterBennett I should've specified sorry. The big red one is a capacitor yes. The two resistors in this picture are the red/yellow smaller components; above and to the right of the cap.

Comment: @HaLailahHaZeh A Philco 1931 70A Cathedral Radio

Comment: It's a tube radio, so the circuit is running at 300V or so. Resistances of several hundred kΩ result in currents of some mA, which is a reasonable range. If this is a voltage divider, the exact value of the resistors does not matter much, it's only their ratio what counts.

Comment: if it ain't broke don't fix it.

Comment: Are these resistors the type with Body-End-Dot as the color code placement?

Comment: @analogsystemsrf yes!

Comment: Now the real question is how you figure out the voltage and power rating for such an old part.

Comment: @Lundin 430V going across em so I calculated a power rating of ~1W should be good. And there's one handling 600V that I've got 2W on.

Comment: @CapnJack Perhaps something along the lines of this https://www.digikey.com/product-detail/en/vishay-dale/RS02B250R0FE70/RSB-250RTR-ND/1166422. These are fairly rugged. There's also various chassis mount ones, but they will be very expensive.

Comment: @Lundin Hey thanks for that, but just bought them at a local electric hobby store nearby.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Carbon resistors like what's in your vintage radio are not stable over long time periods. In my experience, the resistance moves upwards. I have noticed this even on early Delco Studebaker solid state car radios that persisted with carbon resistors. Your radio probably has pre-WW2 resistors because WW2 made designers adhere to the preferred range which 250K is not. Due to the age of your radio, I think you should replace all the old resistors. Remember that many small modern resistors do not have the voltage rating. It is good to get the chassis to spec so the valves will all be at their correct bias points.

Comment: perfect thank you! Another gentleman told me resistors out of 20% of their original values should be replaced. I'm all about keeping as many original parts as possible, but this seems important.

Answer (score 3):

Your resistors, as you now know, are very old.  Their manufacture was known as "composite".  A crude simile would be an insulating "pipe" filled with the carbon composition and you stick the wires at the ends (or the caps with the wires on as I see in your case).  They are prone to going high in resistance and well out of tolerance.  If they carry current with a biggish voltage drop across them, even more so.  Strongly recommend you replace them and keep your old valves working within their voltage tolerances.

If you are getting distortion in the audio, certainly replace the resistor which goes to the anode of the first AF amplifier.  Typically that resistor was a "half-watt" one which typically would go high due to the "duress" it worked under.  Put a 1watt or even 2watt resistor in place of that one. You would also do well to replace the resistor(s) which feed voltage to the screen grid of the AF output valve.  Even if the screen grid is fed by voltage divider resistors which have gone high in value by equal amounts, I suggest replace to be prudent.  The dynamics of the screen current through one of the old too-high resistors could screw your screen bias and also promote audio distortion.

Old composite resistors can also become noisy, so any crackling or "fried egg" noise and you should target not only those resistors above, but also the resistors at the control grid ("grid 1") of the (typically) two audio amplifier valves.

"Newer" (post-WWII) resistors are not made physically the same way, and are more likely to remain "quiet" as well as hold their value.

I'll try to "sneak" this one past in the guise of answering your resistor question.  Check the DC voltage across the resistor which goes between control grid and "ground" on the output valve.  Assuming the output valve uses cathode bias, there should be absolutely no voltage across that resistor. If there is, then replace that resistor as I already suggested, but the main thing is, the presence of voltage on the output valve control grid resistor when the output valve is using cathode bias, means that the coupling capacitor feeding audio from the previous AF voltage amplifier is faulty and leaking some of the HT voltage on to the grid, and this can also create audio distortion.

But keeping to resistors - while you are replacing the AF stages resistors I specifically mentioned earlier, that possibly capacitor is linked to those resistors so replace it too and then you won't need to eventually ask the next question of "where do I get another output valve?"

Good luck with your efforts.

Comment: Thanks so much for the input. A lot of good info. I did your test and it seems I have a lot of resistors to replace. No big deal. Thanks for confirming though. : )

Answer (score 0):

Judging by the color code (Body-End-Dot) on the ones in the photo, they appear to be 240K (red-yellow-yellow). In the E24 range, you can get 240K.